# Swift3 Как программно проверить включен ли дисплей у девайса?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Пишу приложение на iOS, нужно в определенный момент узнавать включен ли экран(даже если на локскрине). Подскажите кто знает как написать.

Answer (score -1):

Взято вот с [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171495/ios-can-i-detect-if-the-device-screen-is-on-off) ссылки.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Observer UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,UIApplicationDidEnterBackground
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                    self,
                    selector: #selector(MyViewController.applicationDidBecomeActive(notification:)),
                    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
                    object: nil)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                    self,
                    selector: #selector(MyViewController.applicationDidEnterBackground(notification:)),
                    name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground,
                    object: nil)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
      // here my app did become active
    }
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(notification: NSNotification) {
      // here my app did enter background
    }
```

Comment: Это показывает активность приложения, а мне нужно именно экрана телефона

Comment: @ИванЧерепанов почитайте комментарии, там эта проблема рассматривается